How do I make column fill available space without table overflow?
I am trying to make a responsive table where:

Columns 1-3 and column 5 will always autosize to fit their content.
Column 4 will occupy all remaining horizontal space.
Column 4 will never wrap text (i.e. it will always use one line).
Column 4 will have overflow-hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis.
The table width will never exceed the parent element's width.

I created the following MCVE to demonstrate:


.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  max-width: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  max-width: 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Previous</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>KA00000 Michael Smith</td>
          <td>COUNTER_CHANGE</td>
          <td>None</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>07-25-2024</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>KA00000 Michael Smith</td>
          <td>COUNTER_CHANGE</td>
          <td>None</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>07-25-2024</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>KA00000 Michael Smith</td>
          <td>CONTENT_CHANGE</td>
          <td>None</td>
          <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ultricies arcu sed dictum eleifend. Nam laoreet eros ante, ut vestibulum magna dignissim eu. Aenean euismod magna eget eros ornare ultricies. In ornare urna nulla, vitae ultricies nulla suscipit
            non. Aliquam feugiat felis ut ipsum tristique viverra id a est. Suspendisse ultrices molestie turpis, at malesuada turpis mattis nec. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent at nibh tellus.</td>
          <td>07-25-2024</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



The issue with this example is that it uses a fixed width (100px) for the fourth column, thus making it 1) not responsive and 2) only compatible with parent elements of a certain minimum width.
Is there a way I can make the column responsive so it will always fill the remaining space without causing the table to overflow?

Unfortunatelly, the table layout might be fail here: to fix the table at width:100%;  table-layout:fixed; is required & then you need to give a width to each column or let them be of equals width . here is a codepen showing you the idea with a breakpoint at 650px to set a fix width. It also removes the content to overflow from the flow. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWLjOQm  To reset the table-layout to a grid layout doesn't require to remove anything from the flow, but it will also overflow at one point (here is average 550px according to content) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gONwqNz

Both approach will not avoid the table to overflow on smaller screen  Another solution cans also be to break partially the layout on smaller screen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VwJKRwM or set vertical writing mode on a few cells https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rNEMRee  Hoping it gives you a few hints or rethinking

ohhh to do a responsive table where columns 1-3 and 5 auto-size to fit their content, and column 4 occupies the remaining horizontal space with


overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;



so you can use CSS flexbox properties


.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th, td:not(:nth-child(4)) {
  max-width: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.table-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: inline-flex;
}





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <th class="table-cell">User</th>
          <th class="table-cell">Type</th>
          <th class="table-cell">Description</th>
          <th class="table-cell">Previous</th>
          <th class="table-cell">Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="table-cell">KA00000 Michael Smith</td>
          <td class="table-cell">COUNTER_CHANGE</td>
          <td class="table-cell">None</td>
          <td class="table-cell">5</td>
          <td class="table-cell">07-25-2024</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="table-cell">KA00000 Michael Smith</td>
          <td class="table-cell">COUNTER_CHANGE</td>
          <td class="table-cell">None</td>
          <td class="table-cell">8</td>
          <td class="table-cell">07-25-2024</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-row">
          <td class="table-cell">KA00000 Michael Smith</td>
          <td class="table-cell">CONTENT_CHANGE</td>
          <td class="table-cell">None</td>
          <td class="table-cell">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ultricies arcu sed dictum eleifend. Nam laoreet eros ante, ut vestibulum magna dignissim eu. Aenean euismod magna eget eros ornare ultricies. In ornare urna nulla, vitae ultricies nulla suscipit non. Aliquam feugiat felis ut ipsum tristique viverra id a est. Suspendisse ultrices molestie turpis, at malesuada turpis mattis nec. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent at nibh tellus.
          </td>
          <td class="table-cell">07-25-2024</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



The container class ensures the table does not exceed the parent element width, The table has width: 100% to take up all available horizontal space.
The th and td elements have


white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;



to prevent overflow and ensure text-overflow ,The fourth column (with flex: 1) takes up the remaining space. the display: flex on the rows and inline-flex on the cells allow for flexible sizing.
so this ensures that the table remains responsive, and the fourth column dynamically adjusts to fill the remaining space while respecting the overflow and text-overflow rules
